# problem with fiting my simple starter model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm completely new in programming of neural network. As a starter project I'd like to make a simple model which should be able to add 2 positive numbers. So far I have a fully functionating code for generating the data.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from numpy.random import randint
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

      
import random
x_train = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
y_train = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'])
for i in range(100):
    a = list(randint(10, size=2))
    x_train.loc[i] =  a
    y_train.loc[i] = [a[0]+a[1]]
print("done1")
x_valid = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
y_valid = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'])
for i in range(10):
    a = list(randint(10, size=2))
    x_valid.loc[i] =  a
    y_valid.loc[i] = [a[0]+a[1]]

print("done2")
```

After that I build my model:

```
model = Sequential([
    layers.Dense(40, input_shape=[2,1],activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Dense(1,activation = 'relu')
])
print("done4")


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse',
optimizer=optimizer,
metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

x_train_= np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float)
y_train_= np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float)
print(y_train_)
```

Last but not least I fit my model with the following line of code:

```
print("done5")
history = model.fit(x_train_, y_train_, validation_data = (x_valid,y_valid))

print("done6")
```

But after the compiler has approached the line of code where I fit my model: This error appears:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5ebcf9756640> in <module>
     56 
     57 print("done5")
---> 58 history = model.fit(x_train_, y_train_, validation_data = (x_valid,y_valid))
     59 
     60 print("done6")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:976 __call__
        self.name)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:216 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 2]
in user code: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function * return step_function(self, iterator) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function ** outputs = model.
keyboard_arrow_right
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your data shape is (2, ). Try changing this line:

```
layers.Dense(40, input_shape=[2,],activation = 'relu'),
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But after I trained the model, it turned out that the accuracy is lower than 40%. Do you have any further how I could improve my model?

Comment: @BrunoEigenmann please create a new question